# VB.net search textbox for string and return it once

Tags: .net, vb.net, search, textbox, return

I don't know why this is happening but I have some code that searches a textbox on the form for a string:

```
Dim strLines() As String = strText.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strRet As String = ""

    For j As Integer = 0 To strLines.Length - 1
        i = strLines(j).IndexOf("&&&")
        If i >= 0 Then
            strRet &= strLines(j).Substring(i + 3) & Environment.NewLine
        End If
        If strRet.Length > 0 Then
            If txtConsole.TextLength > 0 Then
                Call ClearCon()
            End If

            rtxtDefinition.Text = ""

            txtWrdDefn.Text = strRet

            Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=" & strRet)

            rtxtDefinition.Text = sourceString
```

After all this is just processes it and that works fine. The problem is that this gets its info from a game in which you are unable to clear the console, so it keep searching it over and over an keeps returning the same definition. Is there a way to prevent this from happening since the game console cannot be cleared?

Comment: Can't you just save the last position in the string, which was already included in the search in a static variable and just start searching at this index the next time instead of starting at 0?

Comment: So your saying at first scan it, then if it finds one, save the position(using IndexOf?),extract the text and all, then somehow start the search but from the IndexOf?

Comment: Create a variable either outside of the sub or inside it using the `Static` keyword and save the index j there, when you found the &&& string. Then replace `For j As Integer = 0 To strLines.Length - 1` with `For j As Integer = LastFoundAt To strLines.Length - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment, here with code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim LastSearchEnd As Integer = 0 'This variable keeps it's value, it's initialized with the value 0 on program start
Private Sub SearchStuff()
    Dim strLines() As String = Strings.Split(TextBox1.Text, Environment.NewLine) 'Split the text into lines
    For i = LastSearchEnd To strLines.Count - 1 'Start at the value you kept
        If strLines(i).Contains("&&&") Then 'Found the value
            MsgBox("FOUND IT!!")
            LastSearchEnd = i + 1 'We actually keep i+1 because we don't want to search the same line twice
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

That's a broken down example for the thing I think you want.

Comment: I know its been a while but I have been working on this and cannot get it working. Should I start a new thread?